# Como extraer el conternido de un archivo `.p7z` firmado con firma electronicas de Certicamara usando python?

Tags: python, firma-digital, certificado

Necesito automatizar la extracción del archivo que se firma a través de la herramienta de firmado de Certicamara. Para hacer eso se usa Certitool para abrir el archivo `.p7z` y guardar en disco el documento adjunto.

Answer (score 0):

Esos archivos son de naturaleza binaria [`S/MIME`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S/MIME), codificados usando DER que a su vez usa [ASN.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASN.1). Para la extracción misma del `encap_content_info` (nombre que tienen los datos encapsulados en un archivo `S/MIME`) puedes usar la libreria de python [asn1crypto](https://github.com/wbond/asn1crypto/), particularmente su modulo `cms`.

Aqui tienes un corto ejemplo de como hacerlo:

```py
import asn1crypto.cms

with open("ruta/de/archivo.p7z", "rb") as src:
    certicamera_data = src.read()

content_info = asn1crypto.cms.ContentInfo.load(certicamera_data)
signed_data = content_info["content"]
encapsulated_content_data = signed_data["encap_content_info"]["content"].native

with open("ruta/destino/archivo/extraido.alguna_extension", "wb") as dst:
    dst.write(encapsulated_content_data)
```

Sin embargo, deberías verificar la validez de la firma, ya que para eso se toma el trabajo un emisor de sacar una firma electrónica con la entidad verificadora (de identidad) y de firmar el contenido con dicha firma.